# Firebase Admin SDK create user using providers

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to create a REST API for my app using Firebase Cloud Functions. I know how to use Admin SDK in Cloud Functions. It does have API to `createUser`. My front end app lets users sign in using Google and Facebook but I am not sure how to put it all together.

My app has successfully implemented `Sign in with Google` and `Sign in with Facebook` but how and what data do I transfer over to Cloud Functions (or any REST API Server for that matter) so that it could create a user in Firebase with appropriate provider.

**Update for more explanation**

I am creating an app for iOS and Android with some sort of cloud based backend. Right now I am experimenting with Firebase but I do not intend to tightly couple my apps to Firebase and hence do not want to pull Firebase-iOS and Firebase-Android SDKs into my app code. I want the ability and freedom to switch my backend over to AWS or Azure without changing frontend code.

The one (and only?) way is to create a server that will expose REST API endpoints and do the work on my behalf that usually SDK does. To achieve this, I am using Cloud Functions but that shouldn't matter as long as I have API to talk to actual cloud.

After putting that explanation, now my question is how do I let my users login to app using external providers like Google and Facebook and still achieve what I am trying to do. When I let users sign in with providers, I do not have their password to send to backend to create a new email/password user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sample code that best illustrates what you want to do [here on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint).

1. It shows how to create an Express app that handles HTTP request pages.  Learn more about Express to configure it for wildcards are needed.
2. It accepts and checks authentication tokens in HTTP requests from Firebase Authentication to validate the end user responsible for the request.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am still working my way for this but I think that Express app creates user in Firebase using Firebase SDK and then uses token for further calls. I am trying to create a user in Firebase without using Firebase SDK. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks, https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential worked for me